# FancyBox and bootstrap datetimepicker didn't cooperate each other

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fancybox, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have a problem with two jquery plugins: fancyBox v2.1.5 and bootstrap datetimepicker. They can't cooperate each other. My js code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    $('.form_datetime_start, .form_datetime_end').datetimepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn:  1,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        forceParse: 0,
        showMeridian: 1
    });
});
```

In this order fancybox works ok, but popup with datetimepicker doesn't show. When I change the order (fancybox after datetimepicker) datetimepicker works but fancybox doesn't.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you add fiddle for this with both jQuery?

Comment: There must be some conflict.  Maybe they're defining the same function, so it gets overwritten?

Comment: any errors in your console?

Comment: I have one error: fancybox is not a function